# How to add cssClass to kendo toolbar based on condition using jquery

Tags: kendo-ui

I am trying to apply css class to Kendo toolbar based on condition. I have a page wherein i have two modes, Edit and Read mode. Initially when page loads, page will be in Read mode. So the kendo toolbar which contains 4 buttons, and will be in disabled state, when mouse hovered on buttons it will display hand symbol. When switched to Edit mode, the tool bar becomes active and buttons will be clickable. My question is how to add css class to make default cursor appear in tool bar when mouse hovered on buttons in Read mode?

```
.k-link{
   cursor:default;
}
```

Above style is to be used in jquery. The Jquery is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     if (var gridEdit == "Read") {
       //css class(mentioned above) to add 
     }
 });
```

How to add css class in the above condition. It will be helpful if somebody can resolve this for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to disable the buttons in the toolbar you will need to do a little bit more work than just applying a CSS class.. Applying a class won't stop the click event from being fired.

You need to apply a disabled CSS class to the buttons:

```
$('.k-grid-toolbar').children('.k-button').addClass('k-state-disabled')
```

then add a click event handler to prevent the click event from firing:

```
 $('.k-grid-toolbar').children('.k-button.k-state-disabled').on("click", disableToolbar);

 function disableToolbar()
 {
        return false;
 }
```

Then to re-enable the buttons you do the opposite. Unbind the click event you added previously and remove the `.k-state-disabled` class.

```
 $('.k-grid-toolbar').children('.k-button.k-state-disabled').off("click", disableToolbar);
 $('.k-grid-toolbar').children('.k-button').removeClass('k-state-disabled')
```

You can see a [working example of this here](http://jsfiddle.net/hx9qrLzb/)